# How to separate JSON objects by commas in a JSON file all at once

Tags: json

I have JSON file that has large list of JSON objects but they are separated by commas. I want to add comma between JSON objects all at once. I found the way of replacing but every JSON object in a file is starting from the new line. Below is the screenshot of file format:

[image]

Here every JSON object is starting from new line I have tried using find replace method in find I have added `}{` and in replace with `},{` but it's not working.

Comment: What language are you using? Can you show the code you have tried pls?

Comment: I am not using any language i am trying it using simple text editor in ubuntu its a json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you replace `\n{` with `\n,{` and then add `[` at the beginning of the file and `]` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, it worked can you please tell what does`\n` signifies..

Comment: \n means new line. Your pattern to match is new line and a curly bracket.